# How to freeze the full application?

Tags: vb.net

i'v been looking all around and can't seem to find the solution, maybe you can help?

I need to be able to freeze the whole application(ALL open forms), and then be able to unfreeze it all, I know you can do `me.enabled = false`, but it only freezes one form and they're may be others open and those need to be frozen too. So to sum it all up I need a piece of code that will freeze the entire application and also be able to unfreeze it.

Also does anyone know how to freeze the whole application when a msgbox is displayed and unfreeze it when its closed?

If anyone can help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub DisableAllFormsAndShowMessage(message As String)
    For Each form As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
        form.Enabled = False
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(message)

    For Each form As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
        form.Enabled = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
DisableAllFormsAndShowMessage("Grover")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using threading!

> Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 = 1 Second)

This might help you, look into it some more if you need